# Why is it possible to write to an unmounted device in linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

In the raspbian installation instructions (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md), it is recommended to unmount the device before writing the operating system image to the device. How is it possible to write bytes to an unmounted file system?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for [so] unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is written to a block device, not a file system.

```
dd bs=4M if=2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/sdd
```

The target is /dev/sdd.